# Objective C Math - Geometric sequence results

Tags: objective-c, macos, math

For my app (OSX, not IOS) i have a geometric sequence (stored in container array) generated like this:

```
- (void)initContainerFor:(NSInteger)maxRows
{

self.container = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSInteger start = [self.firstTextFieldValue integerValue];
NSInteger ratio = [self.secondTextFieldValue integerValue];

// ASCENDING
for (NSInteger i = 1; i < (maxRows +1 ); i++)
{
    NSInteger currentValue = start * pow(ratio,i-1);
    [self.container addObject:currentValue];
}
}
```

User can enter the "start" and "ratio" integer. I want to give a feedback if limit (MAX_INT) is exceeded. I wrote this function:

```
- (BOOL)maxCheck
{

    if ([self.container lastObject] > INT_MAX)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

But this seems not to work. If i enter 2 for start and 200 for ratio i have this container content:

```
Container: (
    2,
    400,
    80000,
    16000000,
    "-1094967296",
    49872896,
    1384644608,
    2051014656,
    "-2113929216",
    0
)
```

Please help to understand what i see in the container (strings??) and how to get a correct check for the maximum value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not compare the value after overflow with `INT_MAX`, as the overflow already happened. Or put differently, by its very definition and semantics, no integer can be bigger than `INT_MAX`.

What you can test is

```
[self.container lastObject] > INT_MAX/ratio
```

to find the sequence element that would cause overflow in the next step.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from log of array, you actually exceed INT_MAX limit twice, when next element become negative. So you can just add check to initContainer: method - if element is less then the previous, INT_MAX limit is reached.

TIP:  INT_MAX is a *signed* value.